TWRP Black Screen on Samsung Galaxy A9 2018
I want to install TWRP on my Samsung Galaxy A9 2018 (SM-A920F). The problem is that every time I install it, I can't boot into TWRP. It is just a Black Screen, and then it reboots into the system.
I tried OrangeFox Recovery too, but the same result. This started happening after I accidentally upgraded my Bootloader. Before that, TWRP was working.
Is there any way where I can view the logs of the Custom Recovery?
Edit:

How was it accidental: I was trying to completely reflash my Stock firmware after installing LineageOS 20, I was able to flash it successfully, but upon rebooting I had a "Secure Check Fail: Modem" error and I tried many ways to solve it, but was unsuccessful. I did some research and thought that my Bootloader was updated, but somehow was able to flash an old Firmware binary. So I flashed a Combination Firmware (Binary 3) for my phone and that way I thought I would be able to solve the error. Turns out that my Bootloader wasn't updated before (It was Binary 1), but my "Modem" file in the "CP" tar has been outdated and it couldn't be accepted.
Version of Android: I have always been a fan of the first Android version presented for that phone, which is 8.0. I updated it to Pie once, but I downgraded it to 8.0. My current Bootloader doesn't accept the 8.0 Firmware binary, but I removed the Signature in the Firmware and was able to downgrade again to 8.0 without any problems, Android 8.0 is working very good, even with my custom KernelSU Kernel.
TWRP: The TWRP I'm trying to install is the one that was working before on the same Firmware I'm right now. It is a TWRP compiled by myself, sadly I lost the device tree. I have one in my Github, but it hasn't been compiled. I'm able to provide a TWRP image, if anyone needs it.


Please provide more information, such as how was it accidental?  At what point did you stop it?  Is it partially upgraded?  What were you upgrading from and to what?

Hey, thanks for the response. I provided more information.
